# GNU octave алгоритмы без циклов

Tags: gnu, octave

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где найти информацию по замене значений ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ, выбранных по определённому признаку в матрицах в `GNU octave`
**появилась абсурдная идея, но для этого нужно научиться останавливать рекурсию без условий  проверки)**
Огромное спасибо, alexlz

Comment: без циклов

Comment: @zhildemon по Вашему предыдущему вопросу попробуйте:

    [i, ii] = min(matr)
    [a, ai] = max(matr')
    matr(:, ii) = 0
    matr(ai, :) = 0

Если столбцы со строками не перепутал
А информацию -- в документации

Comment: делал, обнулит строки по указанным индексам целиком

Comment: точнее столбцы, с учётом транспонирования

Comment: Странно, у меня вроде нормально:

    matr = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9]
   [i, ii] = min(matr)
   [a, ai] = max(matr')
   matr(:, ii) = 0
   matr(ai, :) = 0

Comment: круто)) а если matr = ceil(rand(5)*100) ? так-то у тебя все максимальные по столбцам и все минимальные по строкам имеют один индекс... и всё действительно здорово)

Comment: Действительно

Comment: Чтож, для ответа на этот вопрос надо знать octave или matlab. Я -- увы.

Я попробовал преобразовать индексы к линейным (одномерным). Попробуйте 

    matr = ceil(rand(5)*100)
    [i, ii] = min(matr)
    [a, ai] = max(matr')
    iii = sub2ind([5, 5], ii, 1:5)
    aii = sub2ind([5, 5], 1:5, ii)
    matr(iii) = 0
    matr(aii) = 0